# How do I install packages and a virtual maching on a server that does not have internet using pipenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

I have a python script that I am trying to put on a server that does not have internet access. I am using pipenv to create a virtual environment. Nornally how I do the scripts on servers with internet access it I copy the script, pipfile and pipfile.lock into a directory on the server. Then I make a empty .venv folder for making a virtual environment locally. I then open CMD and run pipenv install and that will install my virtual environment and install all of the packages. I want to do the same thing on a server that does not have internet access.

What I have tried so far:
On my local machine:

- run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` -> to create a requirements text file
- run `pip download -r requirements.txt` -> downloads the packages into the directory

On server:

- copy the entire directory onto my server without internet access
- add empty .venv folder in directory
- cd into directory that contains the python script, requirements.txt
- run `pipenv install -r requirements.txt` (I also tried running `pipv install -r requirements.txt`

Pipenv is installed on the server. I am not sure what the correct steps are on the server and if I need the empty .venv file. I also am unsure if I need to keep all files (script, requirements.txt, pipfile, pifile.lock, and .whl files) in the same directory. Thanks in advance for any help!

Also if there is a better way altogether to copy and entire script with packages I would love to know how. I think I have tunnel vision on this and am unable to see other/better options on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

On a machine that does have Internet access (and has the same OS and processor architecture and Python version, in case you have binary dependencies), run

```
pip wheel -w wheels .
```

in the project's directory. This will download and/or build wheels for all of the dependencies into `wheels/`.

Then, you can move those `.whl` files to your airgapped server, and `pip install *.whl` them within the activated virtualenv.

Comment: Well, you can also do `pip wheel -w wheels -r requirements.txt` if `pip wheel -w wheels .` couldn't find the deps.

Comment: Ok. That downloaded all of the packages into the wheels directory. I copied the directory to the server and ran ```pip install *.whl```  in the project directory and got the error 'WARNING: Requirement '*.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist". I tried running the command in the wheel directory as well and got the same error. It is possible I am not running a virtual environment yet on the server but also this is not seeing all the .whl files.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did what you said. I few things I did wrong for those newbies like me. I did not have my virtual environment on my server. To fix this I ran ```python -m venv venv``` to create the environment. I then ran ```venv\Scripts\activate``` to activate the environment. After that inside my project directory(not the wheels directory) I ran ```pip install --no-index --find-links=wheels -r requirements.txt``` which installed all of my packages. Thanks AKX for you help!